# Declaration Error: Variable name "x" already in use

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

When calling a method that uses a local variable twice, I'm getting this error.

[Example smartpy link](https://smartpy.io/releases/20210118-6f466eee56038df8fda8b2f77819b83398346296/ide?cid=QmToqxzg954gpHDeF3gbP7dsSLyBgks1kmkCi7P5Fv9XAi&k=770cb6f6ad673c53d38e). In this linked code I added a new method `test_string_of_nat2` which triggers this behavior.

How should this type of function be called if it's needed more than once within the same entry point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sp.private_lambda` decorator.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for this example. Though, when using it on an off_chain_view I'm getting the error `Missing private variable string_of_nat` Is it not possible to use within off_chain_views? What could I do if I want to use them here?
https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmTzqbNsLWSEnW2LtcRY5VjhauKJ4mSR57xvvj2SimZ6ks&k=ec28b8aa14ccfcdc3726