# Missing private variable when using private lambda on offchain view

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm getting the error Missing private variable string_of_nat Is it not possible to use private lambdas within off_chain_views? What could I do if I want to use them here?

https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmTzqbNsLWSEnW2LtcRY5VjhauKJ4mSR57xvvj2SimZ6ks&k=ec28b8aa14ccfcdc3726

I ended up needing a private lambda because I'm needing to call a function that uses a local variable from an offchain view as described on this question
[Declaration Error: Variable name "x" already in use](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4045/declaration-error-variable-name-x-already-in-use)

I need a function that uses a local variable on an offchain view because I'm dynamically loading tokens' metadata on its respective offchain view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private variables are not allowed in views.

You can define a lambda with `sp.build_lambda(…)`.
You can put it in a local variable or not.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.